# SQL remove not alphabetic characters from string

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql

I am a beginner in SQL I have a column with strings, I need to remove any character that is not between A-Z and a-z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(col, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a66c06b4898757b37437cec33cdd9d6d) is a db<>fiddle.